# load library from library

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

i have made a library called EventListener.jar. It represents a simple listenerinterface which makes less work to set up a listener than normal. and i have made a library called propertylist.jar. this is a list which is a little bit like the observable list of javafx. it tracks changes in the list and on the objects in the list. for this im using the library eventlistener in my propertylist.class.
now if i import the propertylist library in any other project and use the propertylist, i cant use the method "getListenerPool()" because it is a method of eventlistener and eclipse does not know the eventlistenerlibrary until i import it, too.

i want to know if i can import in the propertylist the eventlistener somehow in a way, to make the eventlistener in my new project visible without importing it directly in this project

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Java itself does not provide anything here. But you can use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage dependencies. Maven integrates nicely with eclipse.

However if the problem is that simple this might be overkill.

Comment: Yea, i already thought about maven and i asked some other people who meant i should use it. but my eventlistener is just made of 5 classes which have together about 200-400 lines of code i think. so im thinking about copy-pasting those classes into my propertylist project